# Checking a created object attribute in a step definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, cucumber

I have a series of steps in a cucumber test

I'm filling in various things

```
When I fill in "field" with "data"
  fill_in field, with: "data"
And I fill in "nested_field" with "nested data"
```

then
    And I submit
        click_button "Create"

Afterwards I want to check that the object (and it's nested objects) were created in the database.

```
Then some objects were created with the data
   @new_object = Object.last
   @new_object.field == "data"
   @nested_object = @new_object.nested
   @nested_object.nested.field == "nested data"
```

Problem:
 whilst my @new_object appears to exist, @new_object.field is returning nil.

Any idea how I can:
a) Adding to test
When I puts @new_object I get the following

@new_object = Object.last returns
    #

@new_object = Object.all

returns

```
#<Object id: 15, attribute_1: "blah", created_at: "2013-10-30 21:45:01", updated_at: "2013-10-30 21:45:01",    end_date: "2015-04-30 00:00:00">
```

(in an array, which the formatting seems to want to delete)

Which is basically what I want, except it's inside an array

b) I want to retrieve attributes from it but it just won't let me. Works fine in the console... Could it be something to do with cancan authorisation?

Comment: `@new_object.field == "data"` it should be `@new_object.field = "data"`

Comment: For a) you can `logger.debug(@new_object)` or `puts @new_object.inspect`, or, with the fantastic `Pry`, insert `binding.pry` into your code and inspect til your heart's content.

Comment: Ok. Got the puts working just by adding it to the step, though I'm sure the options above are much funkier... 

    #<new_object:0x007f9d3c8a34d8>

I'm expecting an object with attributes to it...